# How do I emulate a storage card in Windows Mobile 6?

Tags: c#, windows, mobile, storage, emulation

I have seen in many programs such as FreeOTFE that they can emulate a storage card in WinMo. It will be shown in Windows Mobile just as a storage card is inserted and i can interact with it just like a SD Card.

How do i implement that? Any tips/tricks/guides/samples?

I am using WinMo 6 Professional with Dot Net Framework :)
I know i have to use C++ with some Native APIs :) But i need to know which ones :(

Thanx a lot in advance :)

Comment: Look at the FSD (File System Driver) Reference: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa912259.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that by means of simple application level APIs. The example you mention, FreeOTFE, installs a custom storage device driver that is identified by the file system manager in the OS as FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY, which together with the FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY means "storage card" / "removable media".

Comment: Yes i know it cannot be done with application level APIs and i know that i do need Native APIs. :)
So my problem is how do i create this storage device driver? :S
I tried contacting Sarah Dean who is the creator of FreeOTFE, but no luck :S

Comment: You can download all the source code. I'm looking at it right now.

Comment: @Ranhiru: Look at the FSD (File System Driver) Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa912259.aspx